# SimpleDateFormat not formatting offset date time correctly

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-format, timezone-offset

I got a timestamp as follows, 2019-10-17T07:10:39.021+10:30 but when I parse through the SimpleDateFormat then print again, it appear as 2019-10-17T07:40:39.021+11:00

Looks like it added the 30min to time then change the time zone. Is there is a way to fix that.

```
        Date date = null;       
        String value = "2019-10-17T07:10:39.021+10:30";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.getDefault());       
        System.out.println("input :" + value);
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("output :" + sdf.format(date));
```

Result

input :2019-10-17T07:10:39.021+10:30

output :2019-10-17T07:40:39.021+11:00

Should be same as input.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date string you have `2019-10-17T07:10:39.021+10:30`consists of [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), so from java-8 you can use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);

System.out.println(dateTime.toString());   //2019-10-17T07:10:39.021+10:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `Locale.getDefault()`, that parameter is not necessary.  Can you try just calling it as below,

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

Comment: While you are correct that `Locale.getDefault()` is not necessary, removing it doesn’t help the situation.